# How can I shake ViewPager to show the user that there are more pages available?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, user-experience

I have a ViewPager in my app, and I'd like it to shake when it is loaded for the first time. This is to show the user that there are more pages available. How can I achieve that programmatically?

However, I don't want the pager to automatically scroll to the next page.

Comment: Image slider may b a good approach for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ViewPager` has a method for swiping programmatically: `fakeDragBy`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#fakeDragBy(float)

Here's how you can achieve this:

- Call `viewPager.beginFakeDrag()`
- Start an animator. In the `AnimatorUpdateListener` override `onAnimationUpdate` so it calls `viewPager.fakeDragBy()`
- In the `AnimatorListener` override `onAnimationEnd` so it calls `viewPager.endFakeDrag()`  After this call, the `ViewPager` should settle back to the initial page.

vpaliyX's answer using translation won't show the next page.  You need to use `fakeDragBy` so that the user can briefly see the edge of the next page.

---

As requested, here is a code snippet:

```
    private float drag;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mViewPager.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mViewPager.beginFakeDrag();
                drag = 0;
                float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                // 120 is the number of dps you want the page to move in total
                ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 120 * density);
                animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                        float progress = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                        mViewPager.fakeDragBy(drag - progress);
                        drag = progress;
                    }
                });
                animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) { }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                        mViewPager.endFakeDrag();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) { }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) { }
                });
                animator.setDuration(400);
                animator.start();
            }
        }, 300);

    }
```

I put in a 300 ms start delay.  I don't really know if that's necessary or not.

Note the expression `drag - progress` which gives a negative number.  To get a leftward swipe, you have to use a negative value.

Also note that I didn't include any code to determine if this was the first time the app was opened.

You can play with the start delay, the animation duration, and the number of dps to swipe until you get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm having trouble with `AnimatorUpfateListener` though, and would appreciate a code snippet to see how it works with `ViewPager`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shake it, you can use animation for it.

I had done the same stuff for `FloatingActionButton`, and it worked perfectly.

For `ViewPager` check out this code:

```
ObjectAnimator shakeAnimation=ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourViewPager,View.TRANSLATION_X,-25f,25f);
                                        shakeAnimation.setDuration(100);
                                        shakeAnimation.setRepeatCount(2);
                                        shakeAnimation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                                yourViewPager.setTranslationY(0f);
                                            }
                                        });
                                        shakeAnimation.start();
```

You can adjust the translation as convenient for, in my case it's just [-25,25].Also you can set a duration of animation, and the repeat count.

You can use this code for your `ViewPager` when the data has been loaded for the first time, however, you need to determine when the data has been loaded for the first time. But I don't think you will have problems with that.

Good luck!